# vertical align center div bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to center my Container in the middle of the page using Bootstrap 4.

```
<section id="film">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <img src="images\laravel.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <img src="images\logo.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The `justify-content-center` aligns the form horizontally, but I can't figure out how to align it vertically. I have tried to use `align-items-center` and `align-self-center`, but it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

[image: vertical aligin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `align-self-center` to **col** element instead of card-body

See this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="film">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <img src="https://viettelpay.vn/assets/img/website/anh%20thumb.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <img src="https://www.drupalexp.com/sites/all/themes/dexp_drupalexp/logo.svg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```